# javascript array find nearest date with current date + dayscounter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, object

Please hlp me i have to find nearest date from below objects, nearest date would come as compare to system date + dayscounter.

please help it would be great help for me. here is jsFiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/g7rsp4b2/1/

```
<div class="component" data-datejson='{"success":{"yrdateslist":["October 10,2014","October 18,2014","October 22,2014","October 09,2014","October 21,2014","October 22,2014"],"dayscounter":"8"}}' id="onCampusDate">

</div>

var allDates = $('.component').data('datejson'); 
var dates = allDates.success.yrdateslist;
var dayscounter = allDates.success.dayscounter;
var now = new Date();
var newDates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    newDates.push(dates[i]);
}

alert(newDates);
alert(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var allDates = $('.component').data('datejson'); 
var dates = allDates.success.yrdateslist;
var dayscounter = allDates.success.dayscounter;
var now = new Date();

//Add the days counter to now
now.setDate(now.getDate() + dayscounter);

//This is the key -> Sort by the difference in time
dates.sort(function(a,b){
    var nowTime = now.getTime(),
        atime = Math.abs(atime - nowTime),
        btime = Math.abs(btime- nowTime);

    return Math.abs(atime - btime); 
});
```

Then your closes date should be `dates[0]`;

See: http://jsfiddle.net/g8ezcoz7/